# Keystonejs session

Tags: session, keystonejs

I need some help with keystonejs sessions. I'm working on a shopping cart, thus after a customer adds a product to the cart they move onto a check-out page that forces them to sign in as a user. However, when they sign in the session restarts and clears the contents of the cart.

My question: Is there a way to sign in and keep the existing session and then add the user id to the session.

I'm persisting the session to mongodb using connect-mongo.

I have written `req.session.cart` to add the products to the session
and use

```
view.on('post', { action: 'login' }, function (next) {

    if (!req.body.email || !req.body.password) {
        req.flash('error', { detail: 'Please enter your email and password.' });
        return next();
    }

    var onSuccess = function() {
        req.flash('success', { detail: 'Great you are now logged in!' });
        res.redirect('/checkout');//redirect on success
    }

    var onFail = function() {
        req.flash('error', { detail: 'Input credentials were incorrect, please try again.' });
        return next();
    }

    keystone.session.signin({ email: req.body.email, password: req.body.password }, req, res, onSuccess, onFail);//
```

to authorize the user.

Regards

Answer (score 2):

As far as I can tell, user signin with Keystone [only appends the `user` property](https://github.com/keystonejs/keystone/blob/master/lib/session.js) to the request object, and it adds the user's MongoDB id to `req.session.userId`. It doesn't clear the existing session. How are you currently adding to the Keystone session?

Comment: I'm persisting the session to mongodb using connect-mongo and using `keystone.session.signin` to sign the user. I have noticed that when the user signs in the current session is removed and replaced with the new session with userid as you indicated above.

Answer (score 1):

I am wondering that is there any update for this question?

I've digged a little deeper and found that at `req.session.reganete()` in `keystone.session` clean the previous session, and the code in keystone looks all good.

I ended up put anonymous user Cart into as an object and at `keystone.signin` success callback reassign the object back to `req.session.cart`

---

[Update after the post]

The session library will clear the session when new session ID issues.

See the discussion here: [Request: Option for refreshing the session ID](https://github.com/expressjs/session/issues/425)

```
const currentSession = {}
// 1. have a copy of current session
Object.assign(currentSession, req.session) 
// 2. merge the copied session to new session after keystone signin method.
// ...
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you could set that in the session. It is just for users.

Instead I would have a `isDraft` field on the the Cart List and save the Cart every change of products.